# Why does changing the sender/from in an Exchange Transport Agent result in the primary address of that user?

Tags: c#, .net-4.5, exchange-server-2016, exchange-transport-agents

I've successfully created an `SmtpReceiveAgent` with `OnEndOfDataEvent`. It should replace the sender of some emails, so the recipient sees the new sender and is able to reply to it.

This already works very well, just by setting:

```
MailItem.Message.From = new EmailRecipient(DisplayName, Address);
```

It doesn't seem to be necessary to also set the following places, like in many examples I found:

```
MailItem.Message.Sender = new EmailRecipient(DisplayName, Address);
MailItem.FromAddress = new RoutingAddress(Address);
```

I am able to set any random non-existing or external address, or any existing address of other users in the same company/domain.

However, when that user exists in our system, and it is not its primary address, it is replaced by the primary address. But that's exactly what I wanted: use alternative addresses... How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No idea why this happened, but when I replaced
`SmtpReceiveAgent` and `OnEndOfDataEvent` by
`RoutingAgent` and `OnCategorizedMessage`,
it just started to work without other changes.

I also added setting `MailItem.FromAddress` now,
so the `Return-Path` header was affected correctly.